# Performance of rowNode.setDataValue method

Tags: ag-grid

I have been evaluating AG Grid component to be used to visualize some streaming data. Unfortunately, client-side model cannot be used since we need to handle big datasets (> 150K rows).  So I focused on server-side and viewport models and found both of them to be quite slow when updating data via rowNode.setDataValue(property, value) calls. It takes about 500ms to update 6 properties of 70 rows. Is it expected to be like that? Is there anything that can be done to make it faster except using rowNode.setData instead?

Answer (score 2):

After looking at AG Grid source code I found RowNode.updateData method that works much faster then setDataValue, but unlike setData it doesn't update the entire row, so animations are still there. Not sure why this method is not documented though.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, where there was a grid with almost 3200+ row-nodes as well as enabled `rowGroup` with checkbox selection.
When I select the checkbox for node or `rowGroup`, I need to update few properties based on selection. This was working fine with `rowNode.setDataValue(isSelected, event.node.selected)`.

But when I select/de-select All (from header checkbox), it was taking around **3500ms** to update the grid, since it was looping through inside `rowSelected`.

I am updating value directly to property, not using `setDataValue()` method.

`const rowNode = this.gridApi.getRowNode(event.node.data.id);`

`rowNode.data.isSelected = event.node.selected;`

Now it's **updating fast enough than before (almost less than a second)**.